# Using "Content" view as EditorFor template in an "Embedded Resource" view

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have an "Embedded Resource" view. In this view I am using the following model

```
public class TestModel
{
    public TestModel()
    {
        CustomModel1 = new CustomModel1 ();
        CustomModel2 = new CustomModel2();
    }

    public CustomModel1 CustomModel1 { get; set; }

    public CustomModel2 CustomModel2{ get; set; }
}
```

In this view I have a form and inside it I am using `@Html.EditorFor` instead of `@Html.Partial`, because when I use `@Html.Partial` the CustomModel1 passed to the action (when the form is submitted) is empty.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomModel1, Constants.CustomEmbeddedView1)
```

However when I use `@Html.EditorFor` and pass as a template a "Content" view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomModel1, "~/Views/Common/_CustomPartialView.cshtml")
```

I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.Int32'.

If I set the "Content" view to be an "Embedded Resource" everything works fine.

Is there any way to resolve this problem? Perhaps there is another solution to the model binding problem instead of using `@Html.EditorFor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I still do not know why the error is thrown, but at least I fixed the model binding.

The problem with the model binding, is that when you call `@Html.Partial`

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Common/_CustomPartialView.cshtml", Model.CustomModel1)
```

The elements that are dispayed (I use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)` for example in the partial view) have an `id="Name"`. So the model binding tries to find a "Name" property inside the `TestModel`, but the name property is inside the `CustomModel1` property. This is why the model binding does not work, and the Name property is an empty string when the form is submitted.

The fix is to set the HtmlFieldPrefix.

```
var dataDictCustomModel1 = new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = { HtmlFieldPrefix = "CustomModel1" } };
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Common/_CustomPartialView.cshtml", Model.CustomModel1, dataDictCustomModel1 )
```

This way the id of the Name property becomes `id="CustomModel1_Name"`, thus allowing the model binder to properly set the value of the Name property.

There may be a better solution for this, but so far this is the best, that I have come up with.